# java mail attachment notification

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I am sending mail with attachment but the problem i am facing is.....I want to show user that "Now it is attaching"....."Now it is sending mail"...such notification.
I am using Transport .send(msg), what it does is it attach the attachment first and then send mail, So I cant able to distinguish what is going on in background.

I use session.debug(true) , it notifies all things to me in console but what i want is some trigger or callback which says now attaching, now sending like that....

Here is my code..

```
public void send1() {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", email.getSmtpServer());
props.put("mail.smtp.port", email.getSmtpPort());
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

try {
Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
session.setDebug(true);
emailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
emailMessage.setSubject(email.getEmailSubject());



if(email.getAttachedFile().toString().trim().equals("")){
emailMessage.setText(email.getEmailBody());
}else{
attachFile(email.getAttachedFile());
}

emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new          InternetAddress(email.getEmailTo(),"XYZ"));

Transport transport=session.getTransport("smtp");

transport.addConnectionListener(new EmailTransportListener(callBackObject));
transport.addTransportListener(new EmailTransportListener(callBackObject));

transport.connect();

InternetAddress[] a=new InternetAddress[1];
a[0]=new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com");
transport.sendMessage(emailMessage,a);

} catch (Exception mex) {
mex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

---

Here I am writing my attachment code.....

```
private int attachFile(File file){
try {

// Create the message part
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

// Fill the message

messageBodyPart.setText(email.getEmailBody());

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// Part two is attachment
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("greetings");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// Put parts in message
emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

} catch (MessagingException e) {

}
return 1;
}
```